# How to get the ID of current page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

how to get the id of a page.

If you could help.

Thanks

Comment: Get the URL in javascript by : 
url = window.location.pathname;
Then parse the URL... by regex..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're always expecting it to be the last part of the url then you could do this:

```
var splits = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var id = -1;
if(splits.length > 0)
   id = splits[splits.length -1];
```

Comment: is it safe as far as SQL injection and other treats are out there?

Comment: You're just getting the index from the url with javascript. For injection it depends how you're constructing your database statements on the backend for whether or not injection would be an issue.

Comment: Thanks I see you edited to check the splits.length to be greater than 0 .. mine would always have an id, is that necessary?